# Order by first author only (not all names) than by year or Sort by a partial entry in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I need to sort my biblatex entries on the base of the first author only (authortitle style), but I need the complete list of authors in the bibliography. I can use something like

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{mio}{
 \sort{\field{author}}
}
```

but how can I extract the first author only?
Otherwise said, how can I extract partial infos from bibtex entries (the first author as an example?)

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

**I use biblatex biber teklive**

**Order of reference here should be the inverse**

[image]

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[natbib = true, backend = biber, style = authoryear, sorting = nyt]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{A2014,
author={A,B and C,D},
title={Test},
year = {2014}
}

@article{A2000,
author={A,B and D,E},
title={Test},
year = {2000}
}

\end{filecontents} 

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

I have the answer right now, but I edited the question anyway because I think this could be a common problem for newbies like me and I didn't find an example on the net

Therefore, please answer this question giving also some detail about the use of `sortname`, `\DeclareSourcemap` `\DeclareSortingScheme` to help me learn.

Comment: How is the normal sorting scheme inadequate? Normally it is sorted by author, with secondary and subsequent authors only coming into play with multi-author works, but still sorted by primary author.

Comment: Please, post a MWE or a example of what you want. For example, in the sorting is only necessary the lastname of the first author or you need sorting using the fullname of the fisrt author. Depending of you answer the approach  is different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How I commented in your question I see two possibilities for sorting the bibliographies entries:

### The first: Using only the Last Name of the First Author

How you are using `biber`, you are able to use `labelalpha` (biblatex.pdf. page 59). Using `labelalpha` you can use only one author, with the `maxalphanames`. Then if it is set to `1` biber only use the first author (really the lastname) for make the `labelalpha`. Finally, it is necessary to specify a sorting scheme that use `labelalpha` for example `anyt` (Page 254, biblatex.pdf). Then load `biblatex` whith:

```
\usepackage[maxalphanames=1,labelalpha,maxbibnames=99, sorting=anyt, style=authoryear, natbib=true,  backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@article{A2014,
author={A,B and C,D},
title={Test},
year = {2014}
}

@article{A2000,
author={A,B and D,E},
title={Test},
year = {2000}
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[maxalphanames=1,labelalpha,maxbibnames=99, sorting=anyt, style=authoryear, natbib=true,  backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `maxbibanames=99` is for printed the full authors in the bibliography.

### The second: Using the fullname of the First Author

This is possible using `DeclareStyleSourcemap`. The most the default alphabetic sorting schemes of `biblatex` are able to use `sortname` field. Then it is possible use `DeclareStyleSourcemap` for copy the fullname of the first author in the `sortname` field.  For a explains about `Regular Expressions` read the `perl` documentation [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html).

```
\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
        \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{(.+)\sand}, final]
        \step[fieldset=sortname, fieldvalue=$1, final]  }
}}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@article{A2014,
author={A,Bo and M,M},
title={Test},
year = {2014}
}

@article{A2000,
author={A,Co and D,E},
title={Test},
year = {2000}
}

\end{filecontents}

\RequirePackage[maxbibnames=99, sorting=nyt, style=authoryear,  backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
        \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{(.+)\sand}, final]
        \step[fieldset=sortname, fieldvalue=$1, final]  }
}}

\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me the first solution does not work (using Biber 1.9). The second works fine.

Comment: is there a solution for backend=bibtex8?

Comment: The `sorting=anyt` seems to break down with additional references by only one author. How can one handle such a case?

Comment: If you have more than 2 authors and you still want to use just the first for sorting, replace `(.+)\sand` with `(.+?)\sand` in the regexp{}-function -- otherwise only the last is removed for sorting

Comment: I modified the line to `\step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{([^,]+),\s+(.).*?\sand}, final]`. this gives me sorting by first author, first initial (i.e. J. Smith and James Smith are sorted the same). Don't know if it works with prefixes/postfixes.

Comment: At first this didn't work for me (the second solution), then I realised that it's important that the `\DeclareStyleSourcemap{...}` part comes _before_ `\addbibresource{MWE.bib}`.

Comment: Because `labelalpha` looks like `Xy07`, the first solution will sort publications >2000 before publications <2000. I think it also fails to distinguish between authors with the same name. So it require you to redefine `labelalpha` with `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`.

I do prefer this solution because it allows you to sort by second author (and third, etc) when there are multiple publications by the same first author for a given year.