# Why is this bibliography not sorted by year?

Tags: biblatex

The following MWE has three entries by the same author from different years. However, when compiled, the bibliography puts the entries in 2004, 2007, 1996 order.

With the option `labelalpha` (or `sort=anyt` removed), the behaviour goes away. But I don't understand why these options affect the ordering of these entries. (I thought they only affected the ordering of entries with identical authors and years.)

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{Costello-1996-Super-reform-press-release,
  author = {Peter Costello},
  year   = {1996},
  date   = {1996-08-20},
  note   = {Press release},
  title  = {Superannuation reform},
  url    = {http://www.budget.gov.au/1996-97/pressreleases/budgetp4.pdf}
}

@Misc{Costello-2007-Income-tax-cuts-press-release,
  author = {Peter Costello},
  title  = {Australians to benefit from 1 July},
  year   = {2007},
  date   = {2007-06-26},
  url    = {http://ministers.treasury.gov.au/DisplayDocs.aspx?doc=pressreleases/2007/054.htm&pageID=003&min=phc&Year=&DocType=0},
  note   = {Press release No. 054},
}

@Misc{Costello-2004-callback-interview-PHI-take-up-rates-for-seniors-much-higher,
  author = {Peter Costello},
  title  = {Interview with Liam Bartlett, 720 ABC Perth},
  year   = {2004},
  date   = {2004-09-28},
  url    = {http://www.petercostello.com.au/transcripts/2004/2674-alp-advertisements-the-greens-interest-rates-the-economy-childcare-taxation-private-health-insurance-interview-with-liam-bartlett-abc-radio-720}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,singletitle,style=authoryear-ibid,ibidtracker=strict, autocite=footnote, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=9, uniquelist=false, uniquename=init,sorting=anyt,labelalpha,maxalphanames=1]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Costello-1996-Super-reform-press-release,Costello-2007-Income-tax-cuts-press-release,Costello-2004-callback-interview-PHI-take-up-rates-for-seniors-much-higher}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `labelalpha` affects the format of the labels - not the sorting. `sorting` sets the sort order for the bibliography. It determines the sort order completely.

Comment: And you're using an author year system but an alpha sorting system. These are not designed to work together. The `anyt` sorting system only works with alphabetic type systems.

Comment: @AlanMunn Indeed. See my answer below ;).

Comment: Thanks, I was using the answer to this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203185/order-by-first-author-only-not-all-names-than-by-year-or-sort-by-a-partial-ent . I wanted the entries in the bib to appear in the order author-year-abcd. e.g. Costello (2007) Costello (2008a) Costello (2009b) Costello (2010).

Comment: Sorry, I meant Costello (2008a) Costello (2008b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting `sorting=anyt,labelalpha` sorts first by `labelalpha`, which the manual says:

> This default label consists of initials drawn from the labelname list plus the last
>   two digits of the publication year.

Since the last two digits are 01, 04, 07, 96, the observed ordering is provided.

Answer (score 3):

From page 45 of the manual:

> `sorting`=...
>
> The sorting order of the bibliography. ...
>
> `anyt` Sort by alphabetic label, name, year, title.

Your configuration settings for Biblatex don't make much sense because later options are overriding earlier ones in strange combinations. It doesn't make sense to use an `authoryear` style and then use a completely different kind of label. If you don't want author-year labels, don't ask for them in the first place!