# How to sort references by the lastname of the first author and citation style should be <Name, year>

Tags: bibliographies, sorting, journal-publishing

In a single-column journal paper, I would like to sort the reference by the lastname of the first authors and also the citation style should be

```
 (<LastName of first author, year>)
```

All the references are in the same .tex file where the paper's title and authors and abstract are also located.

```
 \bibliographystyle{alpha}
 \begin{thebibliography}{1}

 \bibitem{AnItemName}
  LastName, J., LastName, Y., 2002, \emph{How to write a book}, Journal of MATH, 57, 1093-1111.

 \end{thebibliography}
```

I cannot figure out how to do this even though I have checked

- [Sort by author in Alpha bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13944/sort-by-author-in-alpha-bibliography)
- [Order by first author only (not all names) than by year or Sort by a partial entry in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203185/order-by-first-author-only-not-all-names-than-by-year-or-sort-by-a-partial-ent)
- [Sorting references - last names' alphabetical order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148601/sorting-references-last-names-alphabetical-order)

Comment: I have retagged your question since you evidently do not use `biblatex`. You also don't seem to use BibTeX, you seem to produce your bibliography manually. Before you look any further, check with the journal you want to publish if they have some sort of template or bibliography style for TeX available that you can use. If not you need to figure out whether you are going to produce your bibliography manually (`thebibliography`) or with BibTeX (`\bibliographystyle`), you shouldn't use the two together.

Comment: Manual or BibTex are all ok, as long as the references can be formated as what I said in OP. But, I have many references so I do not want to type them again in the BibTeX  for each subitem one by one. Thanks!

Comment: [Manually managing references](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References)

Comment: If you decide for the manual way, both formatting and sorting are up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If creating the bibliography entirely by hand is ok by you, you can get your desired citation call-out style rather easily. Simply:

- load the `natbib` package with the option `round` and use `\citep{<key>}` to generate the citation callouts; and
- use the optional argument of each `\bibitem` directive to store just the first author's surname and the publication year (in parentheses), with no space between the surname and the (year).

A full example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} % for '\citep' macro
\begin{document}

\citep{AnItemName} % generate a 'parenthetic-style' citation call-out

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

% Note: No space between 'SurnameA' and '(year)'
\bibitem[SurnameA(2002)]{AnItemName}
SurnameA, J., SurnameB, Y., 2002, \emph{How to write a book}, Journal of MATH, 57, 1093--1111.

\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```